# Calling Git from a script in cron job

Tags: bash, git, cron

If I run these commands from the command line it works as expected.

```
git add * -v
git add . -v
git commit -m "This is the latest backup" -v
git tag -a v1.0.7 -m "my version v1.0.7" -v
git push origin v1.0.7 -v
```

However, if I run this in a script name script.sh:

```
cd working_dir && sudo -u user1 git add * -v >> logfile1 2> /home/user1/another.log
cd working_dir && sudo -u user1 git add . -v >> logfile1 2> /home/user1/another.log
cd working_dir && sudo -u user1 git commit -m "This is the latest backup" -v >> logfile1 2> /home/user1/another.log
cd working_dir && sudo -u user1 git tag -a v1.0.7 -m "my version v1.0.7" -v >> logfile1 2> /home/user1/another.log
cd working_dir && sudo -u user1 git push origin v1.0.7 -v >> logfile1 2> /home/user1/another.log
```

Then have cron run script.sh:

```
57 13 * * * user1 /usr/local/bin/script.sh
```

Then the problem is that the tag is not created, nor is the tag pushed.

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: Is this the system cron or your user cron?

Comment: Does it work if you run `sudo -u user1 /usr/local/bin/script.sh`?

Comment: what does your logfile say?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's any number of things which could have gone wrong. Check your cron logs to be sure.

The most likely thing is `/usr/local/bin/script.sh` doesn't work. This could be because it lacks a `#!/bin/sh`, or because it has not been set executable (`chmod +x /usr/local/bin/script.sh`). This is easy to check by running `sudo -u user1 /usr/local/bin/script.sh`.

It's also possible that `cd working_dir` failed because of a typo or permissions problem.

---

All the `sudo` stuff is unnecessary, as is putting a user's script into `/usr/local/bin`. Each user has their own cronfile and this can be entirely done by `user1`.

Log in as `user1`. Put the script into `~/bin/script.h`. Make sure it's executable. Remove the `sudo`s. Run `crontab -e` to bring up `user1`'s cronfile. Then add...

```
57 13 * * * ~/bin/script.sh
```

...without the user.

Comment: This was the perfect answer. I had to remove the `-v` from my git commands and they execute from the script (I may have had a typo too, but removing the `-v` seemed to work instantly. Also, I removed the `sudo -u` stuff & changed this line to `57 13 * * * user1 /usr/local/bin/script.sh` in the `/etc/cron.d/my-cron-file` file & it all works great now.